# How to disable auto-up-adjustment in Autodesk Forge viewer version7

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to manipulate a camera pose in forge viewer (version 7) with some APIs. However, It doesn't work well.

According to some experiments, I found the problem that the up-direction of the camera is automatically set to (0, 0, 1) even if the `setViewFromArray()` function is called.

More precisely, it seems that the change of the camera states is as follows.

1. Some events happened. `setViewFromArray()` is called in an event handler.
2. Immediately, the camera direction is set to the desired direction.
3. Only camera up direction is set to (0, 0, 1) in a second (maybe after the `CAMERA_TRANSITION_COMPLETED` event is caught). Other parameters (like position or target direction) don't change.

I think one of the APIs related to this situation is the `orientCameraUp()` function.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Navigation/#orientcameraup-force

I tried to call this function after initializing the viewer and set it to true/false, but both also don't work well. The followings are part of my code.

```js
    const param = viewer.getViewArrayFromCamera();
    ...
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
        param[i] = position.getComponent(i);
        param[3 + i] = target.getComponent(i);
        param[6 + i] = up.getComponent(i);
    }
    viewer.setViewFromArray(param);
    viewer.navigation.orientCameraUp(false);
    // viewer.navigation.orientCameraUp(true);
```

Is there any idea or hint to overcome this situation?
If needed, downgrades of the viewer version are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Forge Viewer will restore the camera status saved in the manifest for that view after the model loading is completed by default. If you want the viewer not to do this, passing `preserveView: true` will help.

```js
viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable, { preserveView: true })
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

This `preserveView` property doesn't solve my problems directly, but I'm happy to receive your advice and learn about the new property.
Through further investigations, I find another more basic question about forge viewer. So I'll create another question if needed.